# File.delete() method gets ingnored RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am making an app for displaying files from sd card using RecyclerView, I have also added a button to delete the files. But the problem is the RecyclerView gets deleted but the original file does not. The reason it says is the the file.delete() is getting ignored. Any help would be appreciated.

The specific code:

```
holder.Delbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File file = new File(String.valueOf(trackuri));

                    file.delete();


                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Deleted the file : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mContext.getContentResolver().delete(trackuri, null,null);
                mMusic.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position,mMusic.size());


            }
        });
```

The entire code of the Adapter class:

```
public class MusicAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MusicAdapter.MusicViewHolder>  {

    Context mContext;
    List<Music> mMusic;
    BitmapDrawable mPlaceholder;
    LruCache<Long, Bitmap> mBitmapCache;
    public Uri track;

    private int selectedPosition;


    public MusicAdapter(Context context, List<Music> music) {
        mMusic = new ArrayList<>();
        if(music != null) {
            mMusic.addAll(music);
        }
        mContext = context;
        mPlaceholder = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_music_note_black_48dp);
        // Get the maximum size of byte we are allowed to allocate on the VM head and convert it to bytes.
        int maxSize = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        // Divide the maximum size by eight to get a adequate size the LRU cache should reach before it starts to evict bitmaps.
        int cacheSize = maxSize / 8;
        mBitmapCache = new LruCache<Long, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {

            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(Long key, Bitmap value) {
                // returns the size of bitmaps in kilobytes.
                return value.getByteCount() / 1024;
            }
        };
    }
    /**
     * Adds a {@link Music} item to the Adapter.
     * @param
     */
    /**
     * Adds a {@link List} of {@link Music} to the adapters.
     * This method replaces the current music items inside of the adapter with the specified music items.
     * @param
     */
    public void clearItem() {
        mMusic.clear();
    }
    public void addItems(List<Music> music) {
        // Clear the old items. I only do this so that I don't have to do duplicating checks on the music items.
        mMusic.clear();
        // Add the new music list.
        mMusic.addAll(music);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(0, music.size());
    }
    /**
     * Clears the {@link Music} items inside of this adapter.
     */
    @Override
    public MusicViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        MusicViewHolder musicViewHolder = new MusicViewHolder(v);
        return musicViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MusicViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Music music = mMusic.get(position);
        holder.itemView.setLongClickable(true);
        // Check the Bitmap cache for the album art first..
        final Bitmap bitmap = mBitmapCache.get(music.getAlbumId());
        // If the bitmap is not null, then use the cached images.
        if(bitmap != null){
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else {
            // No album art could be found in the cache try reloading it.
            // In a real work example you should check that this value is not some junk value indicating that their is no album artwork.
            loadAlbumArt(holder.icon, music.getAlbumId());
        }

        holder.artist.setText(music.getArtist());
        holder.title.setText(music.getTitle());
        final Uri trackuri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, music.getId());
        final Uri turi= ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, music.getId());


        holder.button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Playrecord.class);

                                                intent.setData(trackuri);
                                                mContext.startActivity(intent);


                                            }
                                            });
        holder.button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File file = new File(String.valueOf(trackuri));

                    file.delete();


                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Deleted the file : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mContext.getContentResolver().delete(trackuri, null,null);
                mMusic.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position,mMusic.size());


            }
        });




    }




    /**
     * Helper method for asynchronously loading album art.
     * @param icon
     * @param albumId
     */
    public void loadAlbumArt(ImageView icon, long albumId) {
        // Check the current album art task if any and cancel it, if it is loading album art that doesn't match the specified album id.
        if(cancelLoadTask(icon, albumId)) {
             // There was either no task running or it was loading a different image so create a new one to load the proper image.
            LoadAlbumArt loadAlbumArt = new LoadAlbumArt(icon, mContext);
            // Store the task inside of the async drawable.
            AsyncDrawable drawable = new AsyncDrawable(mContext.getResources(), mPlaceholder.getBitmap(),loadAlbumArt);
            icon.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            loadAlbumArt.execute(albumId);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper method cancelling {@link LoadAlbumArt}.
     *
     * @param icon
     * @param albumId
     * @return
     */
    public boolean cancelLoadTask(ImageView icon, long albumId) {
        LoadAlbumArt loadAlbumArt = (LoadAlbumArt) getLoadTask(icon);
        // If the task is null return true because we want to try and load the album art.
        if(loadAlbumArt == null) {
            return true;
        }
        if(loadAlbumArt != null) {
            // If the album id differs cancel this task because it cannot be recycled for this imageview.
            if(loadAlbumArt.albumId != albumId) {
                loadAlbumArt.cancel(true);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method for extracting an {@link LoadAlbumArt}.
     * @param icon
     * @return
     */
    public AsyncTask getLoadTask(ImageView icon) {
        LoadAlbumArt task = null;
        Drawable drawable = icon.getDrawable();
        if(drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
            task = ((AsyncDrawable) drawable).getLoadArtworkTask();
        }
        return task;
    }

    public void remove(long itemId) {
    }




    private class LoadAlbumArt extends AsyncTask<Long, Void, Bitmap> {

        // URI that points to the AlbumArt database.
        private final Uri albumArtURI = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        public WeakReference<ImageView> mIcon;
        // Holds a publicly accessible albumId to be checked against.
        public long albumId;
        public Context mContext;
        int width, height;

        public LoadAlbumArt(ImageView icon, Context context) {
            // Store a weak reference to the imageView.
            mIcon = new WeakReference<ImageView>(icon);
            // Store the width and height of the imageview.
            // This is necessary for properly scalling the bitmap.
            width = icon.getWidth();
            height = icon.getHeight();
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if(isCancelled() || bitmap == null){
                return;
            }
            // Check to make sure that the imageview has not been garbage collected as well as the
            // LoadArtworkTask is the same as this one.
            if(mIcon != null && mIcon.get() != null) {
                ImageView icon = mIcon.get();
                Drawable drawable = icon.getDrawable();
                if(drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
                    LoadAlbumArt task = ((AsyncDrawable) drawable).getLoadArtworkTask();
                    // Make sure that this is the same task as the one current stored inside of the ImageView's drawable.
                    if(task != null && task == this) {
                        icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                }
            }
            mBitmapCache.put(albumId, bitmap);
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Long... params) {
            // AsyncTask are not guaranteed to start immediately and could be cancelled somewhere in between calling doInBackground.
            if(isCancelled()){
                return null;
            }
            albumId = params[0];
            // Append the albumId to the end of the albumArtURI to create a new Uri that should point directly to the album art if it exist.
            Uri albumArt = ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtURI, albumId);
            Bitmap bmp = null;

            return bmp;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Custom drawable that holds a LoadArtworkTask
     */

    private static class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
        WeakReference<LoadAlbumArt> loadArtworkTaskWeakReference;

        public AsyncDrawable(Resources resources, Bitmap bitmap, LoadAlbumArt task) {
            super(resources, bitmap);
            // Store the LoadArtwork task inside of a weak reference so it can still be garbage collected.
            loadArtworkTaskWeakReference = new WeakReference<LoadAlbumArt>(task);
        }

        public LoadAlbumArt getLoadArtworkTask() {
            return loadArtworkTaskWeakReference.get();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMusic.size();
    }

    /**
     * Custom ViewHolder that represents the List Item.
     */
    public static class MusicViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView icon;
        TextView title;
        TextView artist;
        Button button8;
        Button button9;

        public MusicViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            artist = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            button8 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button8);
            Delbutton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button9);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: how do you know that its getting ignored ?

Comment: @Rahul when I hover on it it shows a pop up that it is getting ingnored

Comment: have you get the corrected click path in `trackuri` ?

Comment: Yes it play the same song in play function

Comment: @Selvin do you even looked at the  code before downvoting, the value is mentioned there, trackuri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, music.getId()

Comment: @KunalYadav Do you at least understand that **uri is not a file path?** ... obviously you are doing something like `new File("some random string here").delete()` and expect that some file would be deleted

Comment: Then please suggest alternate instead of making fun of noobness

Comment: @Selvin your edit was much better, please don't discourage newbies make them understand where they are wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is with you file object so before execute delete statement check if file is there

```
if(file.exists)
{
 file.delete();
}
```

Comment: Karke dekha bhai ye nahi ho rha hai, mere path me problem hai question k comment section me dekh le, Kuch samjha sake to bata

Comment: i think tumhre pass URI hai file ka , you don't have file path

Comment: check kro ki wo file.exists() false return kr rha hoga that means file path is invalid

Comment: file.exists k loop me toast pada hai jo execute ho rha hai

Answer (score 0):

My question here was quite stupid itself as @Selvin pointed out I was passing Uri instead of a file path, but also there was a mistake in placing of the file delete code, it should have been put after the getContentResolver code, the corrected code is :

```
 holder.Delbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                mContext.getContentResolver().delete(trackuri, null,null);
                mMusic.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position,mMusic.size());
                File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Voico/"+music.getTitle()+".mp3");
                if(file.exists()) {
                    file.delete();

                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Deleted the file : " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
```